# A lot of code in query, how reduce code length in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Question for sql expert what use in this situation?

I need call some query 31 times this is a lot of code, is it possibile use some good option to reduce code length.

I have 31 days column in table my_days + other column

eg.

```
with cte as

(

Select  day_1 as DAY_TOTAL, 1 as DAY, t1.column_1, t2.column_2, t3.column_3 from my_days my
left outer join table_1 t1 ....
left outer join table_2 t2 ....
left outer join table_3 t3 .... 
where user = :PARAMETER_USER and CODE =  :PARAMETER_CODE

union all

Select  day_2 as DAY_TOTAL, 2 as DAY, t1.column_1, t2.column_2, t3.column_3 from my_days my
left outer join table_1 t1 ....
left outer join table_2 t2 ....
left outer join table_3 t3 .... 
where user = :PARAMETER_USER and CODE =  :PARAMETER_CODE
---------

Select  day_31 as DAY_TOTAL, 3 as DAY, t1.column_1, t2.column_2, t3.column_3 from my_days my
left outer join table_1 t1 ....
left outer join table_2 t2 ....
left outer join table_3 t3 ....
where user = :PARAMETER_USER and CODE =  :PARAMETER_CODE
)

Select * from cte  + other join.....
```

Maybe create function and use function insted query in union all?

Comment: *"I have 31 days column in table my_days"*: that is a bad design choice. In database land, you should design to have 0, 1 or many, not 31. So data of distinct days should be represented in distinct rows, not distinct columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `UNPIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT day_total, day, column1, column2, column3
FROM   (
         SELECT /*other_columns,*/ day_total, day
         FROM   my_days
         UNPIVOT (
           day_total FOR day IN (
             day_1 AS 1,
             day_2 AS 2,
             day_3 AS 3,
             day_4 AS 4,
             -- ...
             day_29 AS 29,
             day_30 AS 30,
             day_31 AS 31
           )
         )
       ) my
       left outer join table_1 t1 ....
       left outer join table_2 t2 ....
       left outer join table_3 t3 .... 
       + other join ...
WHERE  "USER" = :PARAMETER_USER
AND    CODE =  :PARAMETER_CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

.. or use MODEL clause

```
WITH    my_days AS (Select 1 as day_1, 'xx' as col_x, 'yy' as col_y From DUAL),
        cte AS(SELECT INDX, day_x, col_x, col_y FROM my_days
               MODEL 
               DIMENSION BY(0 as INDX)
               MEASURES (0 as day_x, col_x, col_y)
               RULES ITERATE(31)
                      ( day_x[ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = ITERATION_NUMBER+1,
                        col_x[ANY] = col_x[0],
                        col_y[ANY] = col_y[0]
                      ) 
              )
SELECT * FROM ct
left outer join table_1 t1 
       ....
```

Comment: @d r  Tnx for answer but very complicated for me!

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help. Still, I sugest you to try investigate the MODEL clause for it can be very rewarding in many cases. You can start at this link http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-11663.html if you'd have some time for that. Regards

Comment: Maybe I could help with some comments about this answer: the virtual table my_days is here just to simulate your data where you have day_1, day_2 ... day_31 and some other columns.

Comment: Here is just day_x and some other columns. So this is just for having something similar to your data to deal with in cte virtual table. There, in cte, using model close the records are generated for every day from 1 to 31 [ RULES ITERATE(31), Further, for every ITERATION_NUMBER (which starts from 0) a record is generated where the values of column day_x are from 1 (ITERATION_NUMBER + 1) till 31.

Comment: In the every record for col_x and col_y the values are CV() which is for CurrentValue meaning that for ANY record created there will be col_x and col_y columns with values defined in  Measures paart of MODEL clause. Dimensons part is similar to Partition by in analytic functions. In this example it just has an Index that will be generated whenever an iteration occures. Hopefully this will help you get interested in this solution. Model clause indeed is a bit tricky at the beginning but it is also a very powerfull one later on.